# How to sort a list of dictionaries alphabetically in Jinja2

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

My sample list of dictionaries is shown below:

```py
mydata = [{'data': [27, 3, 30, None, None], 'name': 'S1'}, {'data': [57.33, 6.37, 63.7, None, None], 'name': 'A2'}, {'data': [2349.62, 261.09, 2610.71, 0, 0], 'name': 'Total'}]
```

I want to sort the whole list of dictionaries alphabetically on the basis of key `name` but have to exclude the last element of the list, which name is `Total`.
The dictionary where the name is `Total` should be the last element of the list.

How should I proceed?

I tried something like below:

```
<div class="table-data">
    <table class="table-theme">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            {% for data in mydata |sort(attribute='0.name')  %}
            <th>{{ data["name"] }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

It's not sorting the data as expected.
Also how to keep the dictionary named `Total` at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reject the element of name `Total`, thanks to the filter [`rejectattr`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.rejectattr), then sort the resulting list.
Then, select the element of name `Total` only, with the filter [`selectattr`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.selectattr) and add it back to the end of the list

Given:

```
{%- set mydata = [{'data': [2349.62, 261.09, 2610.71, 0, 0], 'name': 'Total'},
    {'data': [27, 3, 30, None, None], 'name': 'S1'}, 
    {'data': [57.33, 6.37, 63.7, None, None], 'name': 'A2'},]
-%}

{% for data in 
    mydata | rejectattr('name', '==', 'Total') | sort(attribute='name') | list 
    + mydata | selectattr('name', '==', 'Total') | list 
%}
  {{ data["name"] }}
{% endfor %}
```

This yields:

```
  A2 
 
  S1 
 
  Total
```